# crystal report 2013 parameter reduce list to certain values

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I am new to crystal and am hoping for some help. I am trying to create a parameter from a table that includes more values that I want my end-user to have to sift through.

Is there a way to confine the list to a certain list? For example, I want my end-users to only see any string that starts with "CC" and ignore the rest in that table.

Any input would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Lindsay

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your questions, and forgive me if I am not, I would use the LIKE statement and the "%" wildcard...

SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE fieldname LIKE 'CC%';